# Add dropdown values to database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Working on a project where I have a button that creates drop down menus. The menu information is generated from a database. When I try to loop through everything to put the selected drop down values into the database, nothing is happening. Any ideas?

PHP and HTML file:
Waits until the "finish" button is clicked, then goes through the database to create an array of what values I want inserted into the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php 
include 'tools.php';
session_start(); 
require_once "sessionVerify.php";
?>

<script language="javascript">
i=1;
function addCourse(){
    var table=document.getElementById("courseList");
    var clnNode=document.getElementById("courserow").cloneNode(true);
    var clnNode2=document.getElementById("questionRow").cloneNode(true);
    var clnNode3=document.getElementById("ratingSelects").cloneNode(true);  
    table.insertBefore(clnNode,table.lastChild);
    table.insertBefore(clnNode2,table.lastChild);
    table.insertBefore(clnNode3,table.lastChild);
}
</script>
<!--
Editorial by HTML5 UP
html5up.net | @ajlkn
Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<?php
if( isset($_POST['finish'])){
    $i=0;
    $courseBuilder = queryDB("select * from Student;");
    $courseList = array();
    while($cb = $courseBuilder->fetch_assoc()){
        $courseList[$cb['FirstName']] = $cb['IUID'];
    }
    $arr = $_POST['enrolledCourses'];
    foreach($arr as $key){
        //queryDB("insert ignore into EnrollmentInput (SurveyID,CourseID,SemesterID) Values('".$_SESSION['curSurvey']."','".$courseList[$key]."','".$val."');");
        queryDB("insert ignore into Tesing (StudentNumber) Values('".$courseList[$key]."');");
    }
?>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Mentor Rating of Student</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Main -->
            <div id="main">
                <div class="inner">

                    <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header">
                        <a href="" class="logo"><strong>Annual</strong> Self Study Form</a>
                    </header>

                    <!-- Content -->
                    <section>
                        <form action="MentorEvaluations.php" method="post">
                            <header class="main">
                                <h1>Mentor Evaluation</h1>
                            </header>

                            <h3>Mentor Name:</h3>
                            <?php printMentors();?>
                            <div class="table-wrapper" style="height:550px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
                                <table >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <!--<th>Semester</th>-->
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="courseList">
                                            <?php printStartingRows();?>    
</tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                                                                    </table>
                                            </div>

                                                <button type="button" onclick="addCourse()">Add Another Student</button>
                                                <input name="finish" class="btn" type="submit" value="Finish Evaluation" />
                            </section>
                                </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Scripts -->
                    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
                    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
                    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

                </body>

            </html>
```

PHP Function to print my form:

```
function printStartingRows(){

    $result = queryDB("select * from EnrollmentInput where SurveyID=".$_SESSION['curSurvey'].";");
    $courseBuilder = queryDB("select IUID, FirstName from Student;");
    $courseList = array();
    while($cb = $courseBuilder->fetch_assoc()){
        $courseList[$cb['IUID']] = $cb['FirstName'];
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        print("<tr id='courserow'>");
        print("<td>");
        print("<h3>Student: </h3>");
        printCourseList($courseList[$row['CourseID']]);
        print("</td>");
        print("<td>");
        print("<h3>Student: </h3>");
    /*  printSemesterList($row['SemesterID']);
        print("</td>");
        print("</tr>");*/
        print("</tr>");

    }

    print("<tr id='courserow'>");

    print("<td>");
    print("<h3>Student: </h3>");
    printCourseList("");
        print("</td>");
    /*print("<td>");
    printSemesterList("");
    print("</td>");*/
    print("</tr>");

    print("<tr id='questionRow'>");
        print("<th>Motivation And General Attitude</th>");
    print("<th>Educational Initiative & Scholarship</th>");
    print("<th>Understanding of course material</th>");
    print("<th>Ability to apply course material</th>");
    print("<th>Oral English expression skills</th>");
    print("<th>Ability to analyze, integrate, and apply</th>");
    print("<th>Ethical standards & integrity</th>");
    print("<th>Respect for diversity</th>");
    print("</tr>");
    print("<tr id='ratingSelects'>");
    for ($xint=1; $xint<=8; $xint++){
    print('<td><select>     <option value="1">Poor</option>
        <option value="2">Less Than Acceptable</option>
        <option value="3">Satisfactory</option>
        <option value="4">Very Good</option>
    <option value="5">Excellent</option></select></td>');
    }
    print("</tr>");
    print("<br>");
}
```

Finally, the function to print the concatenated student names:

```
function printCourseList($s){//this is really print student

    $result = queryDB("SELECT concat (FirstName,' ', LastName) as StudentNames FROM `Student`");
    //$result = queryDB("SELECT *  FROM `Student`");
    // ^^ Unprofessional, fix later

    print('

        <input list="courses" name="enrolledCourses[]" value="'.$s.'">
        <datalist id="courses">');
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        print('
            <option value="'.$row['StudentNames'].'"></option>
            ');
    }

    print('
        </datalist>
        ');
}
```

Comment: Man that is a lot of code for us to go through.  Could you point out where the problem area is?  What do you see now?  Your dropdown menu is empty?  You have syntax problems?  Logs?  Is it a Javascript or PHP problem?

Comment: My dropdowns show values, so that is not the problem. When I add to the database, nothing is added. I think it is in the php isset section of the PHP/HTML code.

Comment: Your HTML defines a form with `action="MentorEvaluations.php"`, so when Finish is clicked, the selected values will be sent in $_POST of MentorEvaluations.php.  Does that work?  Once that works, you can work on the database insert code.  To see the content of your $_POST, right at the beginning of the file, add `print_r($_POST);` in a php block.  Make sure that is what you expect first.

Comment: Please make some general debugging to narrow down where it goes south and remove anything that's not directly related to the issue. Example, when the form is posted, dump the $_POST variable to see if it contains what you expect, gets posted to the correct URL etc.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: oups indeed, edited my comment.